# Knockout.js Observable Array with onlick event

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, knockout.js

Hi I have a web application, I'm very new to KnockOut.js

I have my JS COde

```
ko.applyBindings(new LOBViewModel());
//COMMENTED SECTION BINDS THE DATA TO HTML, BUT DOES NOT TRIGGER ONLICK EVENT
//function LOBViewModel() {
//    var self = this;

//    self.vm = {
//        LOBModel: ko.observableArray()
//    };

//    GetLOB();
//
//    self.DeleteRecord = function (lobmodel) {
//        $.ajax({
//            type: "POST",
//            url: '/Admin/DeleteLOB',
//            data : {LOB_ID : lobmodel.LOB_ID},
//            success: function (data)
//            {
//                alert("Record Deleted Successfully");
//                GetLOB();//Refresh the Table
//            },
//            error: function (error)
//            {
//            }
//        });

//    };
//    function GetLOB() {
//        $.ajax({
//            url: '/Admin/GetLOB',
//            type: "POST",
//            dataType: "json",
//            success: function (returndata) {
//                self.vm.LOBModel = returndata;
//                ko.applyBindings(self.vm);
//                alert("Hello");

//            },
//            error: function () {
//            }
//        });
//    };
//}
//UNCOMMENTED SECTION DOES NOT BIND THE DATA TO HTML
function LOBViewModel() {
    var self = this;
self.LOBModel = ko.observableArray([]);  

GetLOB();

self.DeleteRecord = function (lobmodel) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Admin/DeleteLOB',
        data: { LOB_ID: lobmodel.LOB_ID },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Record Deleted Successfully");
            GetLOB();//Refresh the Table
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    });

};

function GetLOB() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/GetLOB',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (returndata) {
            self.LOBModel = returndata;
            alert(self.LOBModel.length);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("eRROR GET LOB");
        }
    });
};
```

}

**Details** 
My Json is in the following format
[0] = > { LOB_ID : 0 , LOB_Name : "data" LOB_description : "data" }
[1] => and so on

HTML File

```
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: LOBModel">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:LOB_ID"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: LOB_Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: LOB_Description"></td>
            <td><button data-bind="click: $root.DeleteRec">Delete</button></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

My Question is

why is that

1. i have to use `vm` to bind the json into LOADModel so that it works, when i use `self.LOBModel = ko.observableArray([]);` the binding does not happen. i.e, my table does not load the data.
2. my Onlick does not get triggered in both the version of the code, I've tried `self.DeleteRec, $root.DeleteRec and just DeleteRec` as well. Though seems very obvious it just doesnot work.
3. Would the DeleteRec know which record i'm deleting. is `lobmodel.LOB_ID` correct way to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer point by point:

(1) Your problem is in the GetLOB function, on this line:

```
self.LOBModel = returndata;
```

By doing that, you overwrite the self.LOBModel = ko.observableArray([]). What you should do instead is this:

```
self.LOBModel(returndata);
```

Then you should see the data in your table (if you have no other errors). The thing to remember here, is that if you make a variable observable, you always need to use the ()-syntax to read or write the underlying value. If you use = instead, you erase the observable functionality.

(2) the approach with '$root.DeleteRecord' is correct. 'self.DeleteRecord' would not work, and neither would just DeleteRecord. What would also work is '$parent.DeleteRecord'. The problem seems to be that you do 'DeleteRec' instead of 'DeleteRecord'.

(3) your approach is the right one. Deleted my others comments on this point, since Richard Dalton below me made a correct comment that invalidates what I typed here.

**Edit: working Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/LFgUu/4/

Comment: Good answer apart from 3 - 'When calling your handler, Knockout will supply the current model value as the first parameter.' - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Comment: by using `self.LOBModel(returndata);` I get length as 0 where as by using `self.LOBModel = returndata;` i get length as 4. but in both the cases my KnockOut doesn't bind the data to the table. any clue on whats wrong, i've been breaking my head for a very long time.

Comment: You are making the same mistake on the length line:
self.LOBModel.length should be self.LOBModel().length. Regarding the table: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: Hi, self.LOBModel().Length does gives me 4. I get no error in console, given is the json [{"LOB_ID":12,"LOB_Name":"asdasdd","LOB_Description":"asdasddasasd"},{"LOB_ID":21,"LOB_Name":"ODIN","LOB_Description":"ODIN"},{"LOB_ID":22,"LOB_Name":"ASDASD","LOB_Description":"sadsdadad"},{"LOB_ID":11,"LOB_Name":"LG","LOB_Description":"LEads generations"}]

Comment: I've created a fiddle, and after changing lots of code, it ended up that you needed to put <table></table> tags around the <tbody>. Edited first post to include Fiddle link.

Comment: That was not the issue mate, I was not using document.load hence my Table was not able to load the data. Any ways thanks for your help. your fiddle did help me understand my mistake. Thanks a ton.